# Moving a SQL Server TempDB of AlwaysOn members

Tags: availability-groups, tempdb

We have two SQL Server instances on Azure Windows virtual machines. Always on availability group is configured between them. We need to move TempDB on both instances, is there a risk that something can get corrupted regrading data and availability group listener or we can simply execute instructions from MSDN instructins found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345408(v=sql.110).aspx

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `ALTER DATABASE tempdb MODIFY filename` on both secondary and primary. Then restart SQL service on secondary. If you have a downtime window, restart SQL service on primary during that time or you can failover to secondary and then restart SQL service on primary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a risk that something can get corrupted regrading data and availability group listener

No, tempdb is recreated when SQL server restarts. If your tempdb is large, Make sure to enable instant file initialization for data files only.

The instructions are fine and follow the comment that I put in.(will add it in answer later)

Comment: Kin, thanks on your quick answer. can you please add a comment on my question you helped me with few days ago? Thanks. 

http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83114/changing-feature-on-a-database-that-is-a-member-of-sql-server-alwayson-availabil